# How to turn off left alt?

Tags: 18.04

I need to turn off alt behavior that's open HUD menu. I googled enough and no answer. This no point in keyboard shortcast menu, not in gnome tweaks. And no unity plugin in ccsm.
I hope you will help me :) 
Ubuntu desktop 18.04 clear installation from ISO.

Comment: @K7AAY but that's for sure single ALT behavior. That's pop-up menu in all apps vscode,firefox,opera, etc and no one of them don't have Alt in shortcasts

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> invokes the [Common User Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) menu in many Ubuntu and Windows apps. It's not an operating system function. Turning that off is application-specific; you would need to consult each app where that occurs to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap. With xmodmap you can arbitrarily reassign keys. You just need to decide which alternative function or character to assign to ALT so that you don't get the HUD. Maybe a space.